# ComboBox com verificação se já está seleccionado ou não

Tags: select, combobox

Boa tarde preciso de ajuda a fazer uma caixa de selecção com a seguinte função: se um valor da caixa de selecção já estiver inserido fica a vermelho, e se algum valor não estiver inserido fica a verde.

Então é o seguinte esta é a minha selectbox e o que eu preciso de ajuda é que ao selecionar uma opção essa opção fique vermelha e o resto fique verde, e depois volte a ficar vermelha quando neste caso é para uma barbearia, depois do serviço acabar a opção fique a verde novamente

```
<select id="hora" name="hora"> 
    <option >Hora</option> 
    <option value="8:30" >8:30</option> 
    <option value="9:30">9:30</option> 
    <option value="10:30">10:30</option> 
    <option value="11:30">11:30</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: Coloca o código do que vc já tem, HTML CSS JS, fale se vai usat jQuery ou só JS. Sua pergunta precisa ser mais completa.

Comment: Então é o seguinte esta é a minha selectbox e o que eu preciso de ajuda é que ao selecionar uma opção essa opção fique vermelha e o resto fique verde  <select id="hora" name="hora">
                                <option >Hora</option>
                                <option value="8:30" >8:30</option>
                                <option value="9:30">9:30</option>
                                <option value="10:30">10:30</option>
                                <option value="11:30">11:30</option>
                            </select>

Comment: André edite a sua resposta com o código que é melhor.